# List of commonly used function/keyword names

Tags: syntax, syntax-highlighting, keyword

This may be an unusual question, but are there any resources people have come across that list all generic or common functions/keywords used in most programming languages? Examples may include "var", "abs", "class", "int" and so on. I'm creating a syntax highlighter and was wondering if anyone any of these resources they would like to share. I'm aware that specific languages have their own appendix references, and I've used this to construct PHP syntax, if anyone has any of these references I'd appreciate if you shared them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to google for specific languages and combine the results yourself.

Maybe viewing the source of some open-source syntax highlighting tools will be helpful.

Also this site is pretty nice for comparison:

http://www.reservedwordsearch.com/

Comment: Cheers for the link, it's invaluable for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Any introductory book on a programming language will have a keyword reference table for that language. I imagine that any commonly available implementation today will also offer a similar table in electronic form.

Comment: -1 He is looking for "generic or common functions/keywords used in most programming languages", not specific keywords for one or another.